# Possible to have no delay on <Esc> and also have Option+BS work in macOS/Kitty?

Tags: key-bindings, macos

I make use of macOS's ability to press `Option+BS` to delete an entire word when typing and making mistakes.

To make this work in Neovim I have the following mapping in my `mappings.lua`: `map("i", "<ESC><BS>", "<C-W>")`

However this has now introduced an unwanted delay when using `Esc` to exit INSERT mode.

Is there a way continue having the option+bs for word delete without introducing this delay?

Comment: That works perfectly in Kitty (although you have to ensure Kitty has `macos_option_as_alt yes` set). If you can add your reply as an answer I can accept - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal supports `<A-BS>`, you could map it:

```
inoremap <A-BS> <C-w>
```

(OP states that Kitty supports this if you enable `macos_option_as_alt yes`.)

Otherwise, perhaps `nowait` will help, but I doubt it. Fundamentally, vim doesn't know if `<Esc>` starts the mapping or not until another key is pressed or it times out.